# How to execute a python script from django management commands?

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi, execfile

I'm trying execute a python script that is NOT inside my Django Project directory... for example this is my management class that I call with the command:

I need to run this as ROOT because it needs access to the GPIO pins on my raspberry pi. (and I get another error)

```
(env) sudo python manage.py bubbles
```

which calls this script: execfile('/home/pi/rpi/bubbles.py')

```
# /home/pi/DjangoProjects/RaspberryPi/graphics/management/commands

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from graphics.models import Graphic


class Command(BaseCommand):

    help = "My test command"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        execfile('/home/pi/rpi/bubbles.py')
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
 from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

So I'm guessing this is a problem with my virtual environment, is there no way to execute a script outside the scope of the virtual environment? Is there a better way to execute this script using a django command or something else. Am I making any sense at all.

python script I'm trying to call:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Image
import ImageDraw
import time
from rgbmatrix import Adafruit_RGBmatrix

# Rows and chain length are both required parameters:
matrix = Adafruit_RGBmatrix(16, 2)

# Bitmap example w/graphics prims
image = Image.new("1", (16, 64)) # Can be larger than matrix if wanted!!
draw  = ImageDraw.Draw(image)    # Declare Draw instance before prims


# 24-bit RGB scrolling example.
# The adafruit.png image has a couple columns of black pixels at
# the right edge, so erasing after the scrolled image isn't necessary.
while True:

    matrix.Clear()
    image = Image.open("bubbles.png")
    image.load()
    for n in range(64, -image.size[0], -1):
        matrix.SetImage(image.im.id, n, 1)
        time.sleep(0.025)

    matrix.Clear()
```

Maybe I'm going about this in the wrong way, I'm just learning to incorporate web framework with my raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

In your **bubbles.py**, instead of doing this

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):

    execfile('/home/pi/rpi/bubbles.py')
```

try this

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):

    execfile('PATH_TO_YOUR_ENV/bin/python /home/pi/rpi/bubbles.py')
```